# HRD Alias redirecting traffic to?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a domain www.abc.in, which is pointing to x.appspot.com(M/S),

Environment:
SDK: JAVA App Engine SDK 1.6.2.1

Created an appID x-hrd.appspot.com, and migrated the data, and after doing incremental copy, I will go and change the default version to "maintenance" on M/S, and after completing the migration process, i.e., aliasing, at the same time what if my users request for www.abc.in, where the traffic is redirected to ? whether to x.appspot.com(M/S) which is still on maintenance page or to the default version of x-hrd.appspot.com ?

Comment: not programming related. maybe a better fit for server-fault or webmasters. voted to close as off-topic. best of luck w/ your issue

Comment: Check http://serverfault.com for this type of questions.

Comment: Bernie and Abel, my question was purely related to Google App Engine datastore, and that is why I selected google-app-engine tag to post my question. I am wondering why it is mentioned in the comments saying "it would be better if it was posted in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set up an alias as part of the migration process, all traffic that would have gone to your old app will be served to your new app. That includes traffic to a domain that's associated with your app.